Converting HTML.CSS.JS template to a VueJS project
I bought an HTML template which has HTML files with separated CSS files and JS files.
I tried copying the index.html from the template into a new Component in my project named Test.vue inside <template> </template> without the head imports.
I copied the JS and CSS files into assets folder in my VueJS project.
-- src
|--- assets
|------ css
|------ fonts
|------ images
|------ js
|------ scss

I went to main.js file and I added the following to import my CSS and JS :
/* IMPORT CSS */

import "../src/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "../src/assets/css/easy-pie-chart.css";
import "../src/assets/css/fontawesome.css";
import "../src/assets/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"
import "../src/assets/css/nice-select.css"
import "../src/assets/css/owl.carousel.css"
import "../src/assets/css/owl.theme.css"
import "../src/assets/css/owl.transitions.css"
import "../src/assets/css/selectize.css"
import "../src/assets/css/selectize.default.css"
import "../src/assets/css/style.css"


/* IMPORT JS */

import "../src/assets/js/jquery.min.js";
import "../src/assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js";
import "../src/assets/js/jquery.easing.min.js";
import "../src/assets/js/plugins.js";
import "../src/assets/js/selectize.min.js";
import "../src/assets/js/jquery.nice-select.min.js";
import "../src/assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js";
import "../src/assets/js/counter.int.js";
import "../src/assets/js/app.js";
import "../src/assets/js/home.js";



import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'



const app = createApp(App)

app.use(router)

app.mount('#app')


I did also the same in App.vue which I know is wrong but I was running out of ideas to fix this :
<script setup>
/* IMPORTING CSS */
import "/src/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "/src/assets/css/easy-pie-chart.css";
import "/src/assets/css/fontawesome.css";
import "/src/assets/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"
import "/src/assets/css/nice-select.css"
import "/src/assets/css/owl.carousel.css"
import "/src/assets/css/owl.theme.css"
import "/src/assets/css/owl.transitions.css"
import "/src/assets/css/selectize.css"
import "/src/assets/css/selectize.default.css"
import "/src/assets/css/style.css"


/* IMPORT JS */

    import "/src/assets/js/jquery.min.js";
    import "/src/assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js";
    import "/src/assets/js/jquery.easing.min.js";
    import "/src/assets/js/plugins.js";
    import "../src/assets/js/selectize.min.js";
    import "/src/assets/js/jquery.nice-select.min.js";
    import "/src/assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js";
    import "/src/assets/js/counter.int.js";
    import "/src/assets/js/app.js";
    import "/src/assets/js/home.js";


import Test from "../src/components/Test.vue";

</script>

<template>
  <Test/>

</template>

<style>
</style>


I don't know what I did wrong because the page is loaded successfully but some of the css is missing . The console doesn't show any error. I don't know what I missed.

You can't use a framework without knowing how to use it. It doesn't pay off to try to rewrite vanilla template to vue with minimal efforts as there are too many problems to make it work properly.
